# When do the "-uple"s end?

Tags: vocabulary, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to form single, double, triple… and uni-, bi-, tri-… words?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/how-to-form-single-double-triple-and-uni-bi-tri-words)

There's *single, double, triple, quadruple*... — what's next? Is there an end to the "-uple"s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that it is tuple (or, rather, -ple) all the way beyond that:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Origin_of_name

Answer (score 6):

- double
- triple
- quadruple
- quintuple
- sextuple
- septuple
- octuple

Answer (score 2):

Here's a table from on [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/single#See_also_2):

```
Coef  Noun       Result 
1     single 
2     double     doublet 
3     triple     triplet 
4     quadruple  quadruplet 
5     quintuple  quintuplet 
6     sextuple   sextuplet
```

I've never heard of anything beyond sextuple.

Comment: septuple, octuple, nonuple?, decuple