# What are the fourth and fifth levels in this context?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

One can use the terms primary, secondary, and tertiary to describe the first, second, and third levels of something.

What would the fourth level be called? Would it be something like "quartiary" or "quartenary"? How about the fifth level?

Comment: Just as a note: the duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15550/is-there-a-system-for-creating-words-for-ordinal-numbers contains the answer to this question.  The marked duplicate http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25116/what-follows-next-in-the-sequence-unary-binary-ternary contains the answer to this question as part of the question itself and not in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fourth level: "quaternary"

1
a :  of, relating to, or consisting of four units or members 
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quaternary

Fifth level: "quinary"

1.
pertaining to or consisting of five.
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quinary

Comment: In protein structure: "Globular and fibrous proteins may exhibit one or more of four types of protein structure. These structure types are called primary, secondary, tertiary, and quaternary structure."