# Alternative (short) way of saying “a three-pronged approach to X”

Tags: synonyms

I rather like this construct, as exemplified by “a three-pronged approach to physical therapy” (or four-pronged, or whatever). However, I tend to use it too much, and I am wondering how I could replace it by other short constructs with the same meaning. So, I wonder:

- Does “a three-fold approach to…” have the same meaning? I think it does, as my dictionary says of the *-fold* suffix: “consisting of so many parts or facets”.
- Do you know other ways to express this in only two or three words? It being a short adjectival phrase is useful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "tripartite"?  There is also "bipartite" for two, but it doesn't generalize to higher numbers.

Answer (score 6):

You could say a *multi*-pronged approach.

The *-fold* suffix is reliable. See [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/how-to-form-single-double-triple-and-uni-bi-tri-words) to a different question.

You could also refer to different *fronts*:

> We'll approach the therapy on three fronts.

This comes from military terminology (as does *pronged*, I believe). You can also use these words with *attack* as the verb.

Or you could simply use *parts*:

> We took a three-part approach to the patient's therapy.

And finally there is *facet*.

> We took a multi-faceted approach to the patient's therapy.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I wasn't looking for a substitute for generic n, just with a specific value like three. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Several parts of my answer cover use of specific values as well. Do see the link to the *-fold* answer as well.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest "trident" (2 distinct syllables).  As an adjective, "tri-dent" (meaning "three toothed" or "three pronged") gives the exact meaning you want in a very compact form: "His trident approach to the problem proved very effective".