# What adjective means “having three parts”?

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers

In math there's *ternary* and *trinary* for expressing arity. Christian dogma reserves the *trinity*. *Trial*, too, is loaded with other significance. *Tertiary* means “the third” or “in third place.” *Triangular* is geometric, not mereological.

Example:

> Someone suggested to me that subjectivity had three parts.
>   Someone suggested me that subjectivity was <having three parts>.

Comment: Related: [Alternative (short) way of saying “a three-pronged approach to X”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16944)

Comment: @nebuch What's wrong with _tripartite_? It was the word that immediately sprang to my mind when I read the title, and even more so the question; and it doesn't ring of the Axis’ Tripartite Pact to me at all—perhaps mainly because I've never heard of it. If there's something particular about _tripartite_ you feel makes it inadequate as an answer you should include that in the question.

Answer (score 3):

*Tripartite* works, though it rings of the Tripartite Pact.

Merriam-Webster gives the following definition:

> 1 : divided into or composed of three parts
>   2 : having three corresponding parts or copies
>   3 : made between or involving three parties <a *tripartite* treaty>

The Tripartite Pact was the treaty that bound the Axis together in World War II. This causes tripartite to connote fascism. Needless to say, victor’s history makes this a very negative connotation. In contexts outside of history and politics, and especially in technical ones, the word is overall less connotative.

Answer (score 0):

*Trilateral* is the answer I found. I was wondering for the same thing.

Comment: DO you have a reference to support this answer?