# What are the higher variations of 'couple'?

Tags: word-formation

If a couple is a pair or a group of two, what does one call a group of three, four, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for:

> 3: trio
>   4: quartet
>   5: quintet
>   6: sextet
>   7: septet
>   8: octet

.. and so on.

Beyond eight the numbers get a bit silly. If you're talking about music groups, you can use the counters "piece" or "person": a *twenty-one piece orchestra*, a *twelve-person chorus*, etc.

Note that "two" can also be *duo*.

Also see this question: [Can I form a word like "quadruple" for any number I want?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5475/how-can-i-form-a-word-like-quadruple-for-any-number-i-want/5480#5480)

Comment: Few can also be used for a small group of greater than 1, but not specifically defined. Generally accepted to be three (3).

Answer (score 1):

For three it would be 'triplet' (or 'triad'), for four - 'quadruple' and from then on you generally use the Latin numeral and the suffix '-tuple' ('quintuple', 'sextuple' and so on...)

Comment: Some of the 'tuples' have also variations (like instead of 'sextuple' you can also use 'hextuple'), but not all.

Comment: _couple, triple, quadruple, quintuple, sextuple, ..., 19-tuple, ..., n-tuple, ..._

Answer (score 0):

A threesome, a foursome....
To be honest, I've never heard of nor imagined making a word for a larger group. Wouldn't it be simpler to just say, "a group of five"?